# Using Twilio API in Phalcon3

Tags: twilio, phalcon

I want to integrate Twilio SMS Api in Phalcon 3 using dependency injection.It would be great if anyone could guide me in this process.

Comment: Just follow Twilio documentation and use it as any other external library.

Comment: @NikolayMihaylov Can you please direct me to an example. I am a novice when it comes to Phalcon Framework.

Comment: As I said you have to read Twilio documentation. https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/php

Comment: @NikolayMihaylov Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like any other PHP library that you want to use, you first need to check what is the installation method.

As noted by Nikolay Mihaylov in the comments, check the documentation for Twillo here:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/php

As you will see they do offer an installation through composer. All you need to do in your project then is:

```
composer require twilio/sdk
```

Registering Twillo in your DI container is the same as any other service:

```
// Your Account SID and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
$config = [
    'sid'   => 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'token' => 'your_auth_token',
]

// $di is the DI container
// Using the $config variable in the current scope
$di->set(
    'db',
    function () use ($config) {
        $sid    = $config['sid'];
        $token  = $config['token'];
        $client = new \Twilio\Rest\Client($sid, $token);

        return $client;
    }
);
```

References:

https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/di.html

https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/php